# jquery each function

Tags: jquery

I have a loop called from a database, each loop has a link that has unique url. I'm using a modal script to load the link in a div, however it will only work with the 1st link. The other links called from the database won't open in the modal. They open in a new window. How can I fix this? I've tried ($('#ajax2').each(function()) but that doesn't work.

Here's the script.

```
    if($totalRows_games>0)
    { ?> 
    <a id="ajax2" title="Pending Challenge" href="FBaction.php?tid=<?php echo $tid?>"     onClick="self.location=this.href; return false">Action</a> <?php }} while ($row_games =     mysql_fetch_assoc($games)); ?><? }?>

        $('#ajax2').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href'); //get the attribute href
        var title = $(this).attr('title'); //get the attribute href

        lightbox.alert({
        width: '400px',
        title: title,
        rightButtons: ['Close'],
        background: 'none',

        opened: function(){
            $('<span />').load(url).appendTo('#lbContent');
        },
        buttonClick: function(button){
            console.log(button);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you please shows us the generated HTML that the browser actually sees, not the PHP page?

Comment: The generated HTML? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: The actual HTML that the browser sees.  You do a View/Source in the browser and copy it from there.  That is after the PHP script has been evaluated and turned into legal HTML.  What you have posted here is PHP that is fed into your web server and converted into an actual HTML page.

Comment: I changed it from "Id" to "Class" and it's working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your function and as follows

```
    $('#ajax2').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```